# Instagram embedded code not showing the images on my react app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, instagram

I am trying to use Instagram embeds into my react app, but for some reason the images are not being rendered.

Comment: Are you using http on your server and https on the images?

Comment: im testing it locally on my localhost, i dont think I am using https

Comment: Take a working instagram embed image, put the url on the browser, and force the url to be http, see if it works.

Comment: @gilamran could you show me some example or smth, im not sure I understand you.

Comment: Can you give me an example for embed code?

Comment: @gilamran sure I can add into the question the embed code

Answer (score 0):

This solved this issue:

```
 this.setState({
                    mainImage: data.mainImage,
                    uuid: data.uuid,
                    title: data.title,
                    author: data.author,
                    tags: data.tags,
                    premium: data.premium,
                    preamble: data.preamble,
                    body: data.body,
                    publishingTime: data.publishingTime,
                },() =>{
                    const instagramScript = document.createElement("script");
                    instagramScript.src = "//www.instagram.com/embed.js";
                    instagramScript.async = true;
                    document.body.appendChild(instagramScript);

                    const twitterScript = document.createElement("script");
                    twitterScript.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                    twitterScript.charset = "utf-8";
                    twitterScript.async = true;
                    document.body.appendChild(twitterScript);
                });
```